# C : Use of getpagesize() in malloc()

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

In the `getpagesize()` man page, It 's written that "The  function  getpagesize()  returns the number of bytes in a memory page, where "page" is a fixed-length block, the unit for memory allocation".

Does it mean that if we `malloc(10)`, malloc() allocates `10 * getpagesize()` ?

Moreover, if I do a simple program that `malloc(1)`, the break point move of `33 * getpagesize()` :

```
printf("sbrk(0) : %p\n", sbrk(0));
char  *str1 = malloc(1);
printf("sbrk(0) : %p\n", sbrk(0));
```

display :

```
sbrk(0) : 0x1248000
sbrk(0) : 0x1269000
pagesize : 4096
```

Does it mean that malloc only allocates a preventive big place in memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the unit of allocation for `malloc` is bytes. The page size is used for memory functions that want page aligned memory or work on units of pages. [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) is one such memory function that has "page" requirements for some of its uses.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system gives your process memory in pages.

`malloc` divides pages up as needed to give you smaller allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Page is the smallest unit used when the OS allocates memory to a process.

In C, the smallest unit is the size of 1 `char` (which consists of at least 8 bits).

The unit for `malloc` is `sizeof(char)`, which is often referred to as 1 byte.

So `malloc(10)` allocates 10 bytes, not 10 pages.

Answer (score 0):

in modern os like windows or linux ,...

memory manager use page unit for allocate block of bytes to process or data block or....

but in malloc its just byte for you

and pagesize just use for os memory managment

also you can read this page for more detail

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Answer (score 0):

No, `malloc(10)` allocates only 10 bytes.

The function `getpagesize()` returns the size of a memory page of your system, which, in your case, is 4096.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the page size is 1 byte, the answer is no.

`malloc(10)` allocates 10 bytes of memory, a page is more likely much more than that.
read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29 for a more accurate description of what a page actually is.

But for a short answer, the answer is most likely no.
Good Luck!